# Override Yet Another Related Post Plugin Settings (YARPP)

Tags: php, wordpress, related-posts

I set up the plugin to show 10 related posts in the options panel but I don’t want to show 10 posts everywhere; just in some places.

Is there a way to tweak `<?php related_posts(); ?>` to show a different number of posts aside from what I set in the options panel?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **limit** option in the `$args` array of the `related_posts()` function.

**Update 1:**

You also need to figure out how will the number of limit be determined. You could have a default number that is then overriden if some custom field exists with a value, something like:

```
  $my_limit=5;
  $get_limit=(int)get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'RelatedPostsLimit', true);
  if ($get_limit>0)
    $my_limit=$get_limit;
  $my_args = array('limit' => $my_limit);
  related_posts($my_args);
```

So in above code, the default limit is 5. If you want the post to have a different value, add a Custom Field **RelatedPostsLimit** with that value.

**Update 2:**

You don't insert the code inside `related_posts()`, you remove the original `related_posts()` and replace it with the above code. :)

Comment: Please where do i add this limit option to? Could you please post the full code by placing it in between this symbol `

Comment: So I tried this and got a php syntax error :(

`<?php related_posts($my_limit=10;
  $get_limit=(int)get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'RelatedPostsLimit', true);
  if ($get_limit>5)
    $my_limit=$get_limit;
  $my_args = array('limit' => $my_limit);
  related_posts($my_args);); ?>`

I s**k at coding